# Single word to describe "make something worse"

Tags: single-word-requests

In a technical report: One setting causes a problem to arise. Another setting causes this negative effect to get worse.

For example:"
When setting the switch to "magic" the runtime increased.
Hitting the machine with a hammer [foo'ed] the problem.
"

I have the feeling that "exasperate" or "expedite" could maybe be used to describe this but that they don't quite hit the mark.

Comment: 'experdite' isn't a word.

Comment: Why not *worsen?*

Comment: You might want to use [Reverse Dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=make+worse) for your future single-word problems.

Comment: As problem already connotaes badness, you could say "emgiggen the problem" - but that might sound somewhat cromulent.

Comment: Just s/foo'ed/foobar'd/ and you've captured it.

Comment: Nitpickery no doubt, but the "something made worse" in your example sentence was the performance. It's not "the problem", which remains the same, and while you can "worsen" performance, that's poorly constructed too. You certainly can't *exacerbate* or *aggravate* or *compound* it.

Comment: I hate that worsen is a word. Its the least winningest word

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Similar in spelling, but more apt in meaning, to your example of *exasperate* is:

**[Exacerbate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exacerbate?q=exacerbate)**

> Make (a problem, bad situation, or negative feeling) worse

Comment: +1 first word that popped into my mind before reading answers.

Comment: ["Look, I don't care what the telly says, all right? We *have* to get out of here. If we don't they'll tear us to pieces, and that is really going to exacerbate things for all of us."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365748/quotes)

Comment: Exacerbate means more bitter, like acerbic, as in rubbing salt in a wound. The question sounds like it's looking for an exponential effect, perhaps.

Comment: @som-snytt do you have any references or examples for this more specific definition? I've never come across it before, and at least in the case of my own personal 'feel' for the word *exarcebate*, I don't sense any such connotation.

Comment: @568ml I meant etymologically. In usage, I did mean exacerbate means worsen but not Armageddon. Not an expert, but here's a usage distinguishing "acute exacerbation" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_exacerbation_of_chronic_obstructive_pulmonary_disease. If an action exacerbated a situation because now everyone is dead, that would be understatement. BTW, re-reading the OP, I now think OP wants exacerbate and not "it crashed and burned and died."  I was extrapolating from my experiences with hammers.

Answer (score 47):

I think you are looking for *Worsen*

> To make or become worse

or *Aggravate*

> To make worse or more severe; intensify, as anything evil, disorderly, or troublesome

Comment: Both are very fine options. However, if it were me I would simply write *"hitting the machine with a hammer made the problem worse."*

Comment: It might be good to point out that "aggravate" is (most?) often used *incorrectly* for "annoy".

Comment: @martinf nothing "incorrect" about it. The word simply [has both meanings](https://www.wordnik.com/words/aggravate).

Comment: @terdon - Your source mostly *confirms* my assertion!

Comment: @martinf -- all the more reason to use it properly and often, thereby reminding people of its actual meaning.  I think it was Philip Roth who said it wasn't until he was in college that he learned that "aggravate" wasn't a Yiddish word.

Comment: +1 for worsen. Sometimes its better to keep it plain.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 7):

Another setting **compounds** the problem.

compound: Make (something bad) worse; intensify the negative aspects of:
prisoners' lack of contact with the outside world compounds their problems.

Comment: Note that "compound" can work both ways.  If the current situation is good, compounding it would make it better.  (The word seems more commonly used in a negative way, and using it to make something good better is an odd usage, bu not exactly incorrect.)

Comment: "confound" is a variant that focused on the negative aspect

Comment: @paj28: confound is something different: cause surprise or confusion in (someone), especially by not according with their expectations.

Answer (score 2):

You may use **[impair](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Impair)**:

> - **to make or cause to become worse**; weaken; damage:

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Impair

Comment: Doesn't quite fit the question: "Hitting the machine with a hammer *impaired* the problem." is incorrect.

Comment: @egrunin Agreed. This appears to be because "impair" seems to imply that it was fine before becoming impaired. Where the sentence calls for a word that means it was already bad, but it got worse.

Comment: @egrunin To me that actually reads as if it improved the situation. Impairing the problem would seem to me to be fixing the situation.

Answer (score 2):

**Escalate** comes to mind:

> become or cause to become more intense or serious.

[source](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+escalate)

Example:

> The [problem/situation] only **escalated** when I threw paper towels into the fire. (I don't know where I got that idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider "**intensify**" (a problem, a difficulty, etc.).

> One setting causes a problem to arise. Another setting causes this negative effect to **intensify**.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think "increase" should only be used for quantitative things (e.g. "...causes the error rate to increase") or for things that have an inherent degree or intensity ("...causes my unhappiness to increase").  Saying "causes the effect to increase" doesn't sound right to me, though "causes the effect's strength to increase" does.

Comment: I would say that intensify connotes and increase of degree over the same span of time e.g. the sun is more intense 11:30am-12:30pm than in the same span before or after.

Comment: See, this one has neither link nor attribution. Could you please fix that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about **deteriorate**

From Thesaurus:
1 worsen, decline, degenerate; fail, slump, slip, go downhill, wane, ebb; go to pot. ANTONYMS improve.
2 decay, degrade, degenerate, break down, decompose, rot, go off, spoil, perish; break up, disintegrate, crumble, fall apart.

Comment: Good option, **but** I think it needs to be pointed out that one does not deteriorate a bad situation, _the situation_ does that. So this does not mean "make something worse", but rather "become worse".

Answer (score 1):

Math can come to the rescue.

'Multiplied'.

'Compounded' -- literally, it means something along the lines of "made it bigger."  Which would seem to fit problems and what hitting with hammers does to problems.